# How to resolve my "loading icons" in compizconfig while loading Ubuntu 14.04 on Virtualbox?

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz

I'm running through the post about [unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) to get my 14.04.1 loaded on VirtualBox.

I've gotten to the step where I run **ccsm**, but it hangs at "Loading Icons...", as illustrated here:

```
ccsm
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : ini
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : default
Loading icons...
```

Ideas on how to get it unhung?

Comment: Did you try the [Ctrl][Alt][F7] to go back to the graphical terminal?

Comment: I did. It just takes me to the blank screen described in the initial issue above (unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

Comment: Same problem at 14.10

Comment: any solution or work around ?

Comment: @CodingRat, If you still facing same issue, there are 2 new answers, could you try both, looking for your feedback .

Answer (score 0):

First check that you are trying to run `ccsm` with `export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm`, or properly exporting target display.

If still hangs while loading, abort *(`Ctrl`+`C`)*, go to *GUI* with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7` and try to hit `Alt`+`F2` to get *unity's shell*, if it works type `unity` and hit enter.

If this doesn't work, still from the *GUI (`tty7`)*, try to open a terminal with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`.
You can also try right clicking on the desktop and selecting the "Open terminal here" option. If any of the above works, try issuing `unity` on your terminal, this should start/restart unity's shell session.

If any of the above worked, hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to go to `tty1` and try running `unity` from there. If still doesn't launch an unity session, try the following:

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

`unity --reset-icons &disown`

Finally, after entering your session, go to *Compiz Config Settings Manager* and check *Unity plugin* is enabled, etc, like your linked answer suggests. Close `ccsm`. Reboot.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ccsm` does not seem to detect your current running session correctly. Your output:

```
Backend     : ini
Profile     : default
```

where it should be:

```
Backend     : gsettings
Profile     : unity
```

See `/etc/compizconfig/config`

1. Check your the current session environment variable

   **`env | grep -i session`**

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
   JOB=gnome-session
   GDMSESSION=ubuntu
   SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
   ```
2. If they are wrong:

   - Logout then login with correct session
   - Or reinstall `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session`, logout/login
   - Or set those variables manually then run `ccsm`

     ```
     export DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
     export GDMSESSION=ubuntu

     ccsm

     ## you can try also
     compiz --replace
     ## or
     unity
     ```

If they are correct, let me know to look for another idea.